# Doubt in JavaMail program

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have created a java mail program to send mails. It was working fine yesterday.. All the mails were received in inbox folder but today mails are not received in inbox and all the mails are storing in junk box folder. Can anyone know why it happens? and what should i do to receive it in inbox?

Answer (score 2):

This will entirely depend on how the receiver categorises emails. It could be:

- You've been put on a spam list
- Your emails contain text being recognised as spam
- The frequency of your emails is leading to you being classified as a spammer
- Any number of other factors - I'm not a spam expert!

If you're lucky, the receiving email system will have a way of explaining to the reader *why* a message was classified as spam. This should help you to fix the problem. Alternatively, the reader could add the "from" address to a whitelist of "definitely not spammers".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your mail client thinks you're sending too many mails? Try changing the sender information/subject.

Answer (score 0):

follow the checklist provided by SpamAssassin to help people in your case : http://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/AvoidingFpsForSenders